# Aurelia emitting unwanted directories

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have an Aurelia project that compiles and runs nicely, but the 'au build' command results not only in the necessary bundles, it also output a copy of two sub directories under my static directory.

It is outputting both /static/img and /static/css to img and css directories in the root of the deploy.

I can't seem to find where this is happening, so any pointers would be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the “Aurelia_Project” (or whatever it’s called). In there I believe there is a CopyFiles task, which is a build utility task meant to make it easy to copy any files inti your ./src directory at build time. Referencing files outside of your project root won’t work when you run the app, as I believe Aurelia won’t be able to find them outside root for at runtime.

Depending on what version of the CLI and which options you choose, the copy files task might have some default/boilerplate helper code to create some commonly used folders for you when you create new project.

Comment: Good try, but I only have these items under aurelia_project:
all are JS and JSON
build
environment
jest
karma
run